# Migrate CRA to Razzle

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-frontend, razzle

I have a project which was build using Create react app.
I need now a server rendering for my App I found about Razzle it is the most simple method to implement.

I have the /src which has all the components in addition a folder for images
Also a few stuff in the public folder.
And node_modules folder
last I have the dependencies in the package.json

Should i just copy paste them to Razzle? Which i have tried and i get errors **webpack_require** and TypeError: cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined?

What is the best way to convert to Razzle?

Thank you